# NSTimer is valid producing sigabrt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sigabrt

```
if([timer isValid])  // << breakpoint here
{
    NSLog(@"Timer Valid");
}
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[timeinterval intValue] target:self selector:@selector(PlayDelaySound) userInfo:nil  repeats:NO];
```

The function runs properly the first time when `timer` is not scheduled. However, for subsequent calls, while debugging, the console gives me the log (given below) logging on single stepping. and subsequently gives sigabrt.

Any help?.
Thanks

Log

```
Single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend, 
which has no line number information.
warning: Remote failure reply: E37
Single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend, 
which has no line number information.
warning: Remote failure reply: E37
```

Comment: By 'sigbart' you mean SIGABRT, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you're missing a `retain`?

Like this:

```
timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[timeinterval intValue] target:self selector:@selector(PlayDelaySound) userInfo:nil  repeats:NO]
         retain];
```

Update: because if you're not retaining, the timer instance may be released sometime, and your call to `isValid` causes a crash.

Comment: Thanks..that solved it. i should now send a release message in dealloc right?

Comment: Yes. You should also send a release before creating a new one. Or you can create a property retain, which will handle the second part automatically when you do `self.timer = ...`, and you'll just have to do `self.timer = nil;` in your dealloc.

Comment: i don't need a new one... basically i created one in interface ...and the rest of the code is here in the question so timer release in dealloc will suffice right..??

Comment: If this is already a property, you should write `self.timer = ...` and release it in `dealloc`. If this is an ivar, you have to release it before you alloc a new one AND in dealloc.